# Isomorphic to Subgroup of even permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

True or False

Every finite group of odd order is isomorphic to a subgroup of $An$, the group of all even permutations.

The question was in entrance exam. I think there is counter example to this statement but i am not reaching that example. Can some one help?

Comment: The statement is true. Just apply the usual version (Cayley's theorem) with a symmetric group and note that all elements of odd order are even permutations.

Comment: More generally, every symmetric group is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of an alternating group!  Indeed $S_n$ embeds in $A_{n+2}$  by attaching the transposition $(n+1,n+2)$ to the odd permutations.

Comment: I expect that $n$ is supposed to be the order of the group.

Answer (score 3):

One can embed $S_n$ can be embedded into$S_n\times S_n$ diagonally, i.e., $\sigma\mapsto (\sigma,\sigma)$ we see that $S_n$ embeds into $A_{2n}$ and so *every finite group*, order is odd or even, can be embedded into suitable alternating group.

(Compare it with similar statement any matrix group can be embedded into $SL(n)$ )

Comment: Yes, but probably $n$ is the order of the group.